# Webpack 2: how to test for file but not compile it?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I'm requiring a bunch of .css files from my npm modules in my main.js file which is the entry point of my webpack config, as you can see here:

```
"use strict";
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        dashboard: './js/main.js',
        vendor: ["fixed-data-table","react","react-dom","jquery", "bootstrap"],
    },
    output: { path: "../resources/public", filename: 'bundle.js' },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: "vendor", filename: "static/vendor.bundle.js"}),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader'}),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

If I do not test for fonts and images, i will get errors building since some modules, for example bootstrap.css, will look for .png and various fonts.

So I added the loaders for testing images and fonts, which now works: It will build!

However, it also processes and outputs a bunch of .png, .woff2, .eot, .tff files to the same output folder which I don't want.

A "dirty fix" would be to make a .sh script where I just delete these specific files after running `webpack` in the terminal. But I'd rather not do that.

How can I change my webpack config to test for images and fonts, but not process and output them to the output folder?

Answer (score 1):

The "dirty" solution is simply to output those files to the trash as such:

```
    {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
            'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=~/.local/share/Trash/[hash].[ext]',
            'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ],
    },
    {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=~/.local/share/Trash/[name].[ext]'
    }
```

It works but it surely shouldn't be done this way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader?name=assets/images/[hash].[name].[ext]"},
    { test: /\.png$/, loader: "file-loader?name=assets/images/[hash].[name].[ext]&mimetype=image/png"},
    {
        test: /\.(html|hbs)$/,
        loaders: ['handlebars-template-loader']
    },
    // Bootstrap 4
    // { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
    // Bootstrap 3
    // { test: /bootstrap-sass\/assets\/javascripts\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
    {
        test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url?name=assets/fonts/[hash].[name].[ext]&limit=10000',
    },
    { test: /\.[ot]tf$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
    {
        test: /\.(eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/fonts/[hash].[name].[ext]',
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? It seems you just changed the destination, not the actual processing and output of the files themselves?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to output assets to another folder?

Comment: No, I wish to not output fonts or images at all. I just need the test/loader to not get errors from bundling the .css files, as some of the .css files have dependencies that are fonts/images - but i dont want them :)

Comment: it may be helpful, https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin or https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-assets-webpack-plugin